# Auto Increment Seed Values get revert back to old value on RDS

Tags: innodb, auto-increment, amazon-rds, mysql-5.7

I changed some table's auto_increment value manually by alter command, but on next day auto_increment seed value reverted back to old value.

**Manually altered value (6000000000)**

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2017-02-28 18:48:41 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table fav_tab;
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Table     | Create Table
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| fav_shows | CREATE TABLE `fav_tab` (
  `FAV_tab_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SERIES_ID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Creation_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FAV_tab_ID`),
  KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_SeriesID` (`SERIES_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_fav_tab_user` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `user` (`USER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6000000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Next day Value changed automatically (207458739 )**

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2017-03-01 11:23:26 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table fav_tab;
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Table     | Create Table
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| fav_shows | CREATE TABLE `fav_tab` (
  `FAV_tab_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SERIES_ID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Creation_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FAV_tab_ID`),
  KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_SeriesID` (`SERIES_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_fav_tab_user` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `user` (`USER_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=207458739 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please help me to understand, why this is happening and how we can resolve it?

Comment: Using that feature can cause trouble, as you are finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For InnoDB tables this is expected and documented behavior, see

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html:

> InnoDB uses the in-memory auto-increment counter as long as the server
>   runs. When the server is stopped and restarted, InnoDB reinitializes
>   the counter for each table for the first INSERT to the table, as
>   described earlier.
>
> A server restart also cancels the effect of the AUTO_INCREMENT = N
>   table option in CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements, which you can
>   use with InnoDB tables to set the initial counter value or alter the
>   current counter value.

Comment: Thank you so much @Anil kumar it helps